# JS - Does class member function is redefined every time when the class is created?

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

Is JavaScript recreating a function defined inside of a class or function every time, when such structure is created with new keyword? Or it is recreated with a pointer to original class to save the memory? Going further- if such recreation takes a place, is it worth to specify functions outside of a commonly and massively used objets?

Comment: Do you know how prototypes work?

Comment: If the function is defined on the prototype of the class, it's shared between the instances. If it's defined on the instance, for example by having `this.x = function(){}` inside the constructor function of the class, it'll be recreated for each instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question could use a little more detail because it depends on what your code looks like. For example, if you're talking about prototype methods, then no, new instances will simply refer to the prototypal method. You can see that in the following example:

```js
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.introduce = function() {
    console.log('Hi, my name is ' + this.name);
}

let nick = new Person('Nick');

Person.prototype.introduce = function() {
    console.log('Howdy, I am ' + this.name);
}

nick.introduce();
```

Obviously in this case, `nick.introduce` is referring to the prototype method (the actual mechanism for searching the prototype chain is a bit more complicated, I recommend some side research).

Another example is actually declaring a function within the constructor. In this case, you are actually creating it every time you instantiate an object. Similar example below.

```js
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.introduce = function() {
        console.log('Hi, my name is ' + this.name);
    }
}

let nick = new Person('Nick');

Person.prototype.introduce = function() {
    console.log('Howdy, I am ' + this.name);
}

nick.introduce();
```

In this case, the `nick` instance gets its own `introduce` method, and all future instances will get their own `introduce` methods. Assigning or changing the prototype method of the same name doesn't matter in this case, because since we found an own property on the `nick` instance called `introduce`, we don't have to search the prototype chain.